# Python - Printing on Same Line

Tags: python, printing, beautifulsoup

I am very new and attempting to learn how to scrape tables. I have the following code, but can not get the two variables to print on the same line; they print on separate lines. What am I missing?

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/sample.html"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

tables = soup.findAll('table')

for table in tables:
    Second_row_first_column = table.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('td')[0].text
    Second_row_second_column = table.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('td')[1].text
    print Second_row_first_column + Second_row_second_column
```

Comment: Can you show sample output. Perhaps your strings have a newline at the end

Comment: @sshashank124 you're right, I misread what the OP wanted to do. Close vote retracted.

Comment: You should also avoid doing the same call twice. Store `table.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('td')` in a variable and then do `my_var[0].text` and `my_var[1].text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns have a newline at the end, so if you want to print it without them, you have to [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) them:

```
print Second_row_first_column.strip() + Second_row_second_column.strip()
```

If you want a space between the two columns, replace the plus with a comma.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I spent hours trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this :

```
Second_row_first_column = table.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('td')[0].text.rstrip('\n') + "\t"
```